# Pouchdb with Angular2, cannot find name emit

Tags: typescript, ionic2, pouchdb

In my Ionic2 app, I have built a provider to inject PouchDB design docs.

But I get this TypeScript error:

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'emit'.
src/providers/design-docs.ts
if (user.location) {
    emit(user._id, user.email, user.location);
```

I am not sure it's the best practice to put the design docs in a provider, so I would like to know what to do.

Here's the provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class DesignDocs {

    DESIGN_DOCS =
        {
            views:
                    {
                        filters: {
                            byDocIds: function (doc, req) {
                                if (!req.query.docIds)
                                    return false;
                                var docIds = JSON.parse(req.query.docIds);  
                                if (!docIds || !Array.isArray(docIds))
                                    return false;
                                return docIds.indexOf(doc._id) > -1;
                            }
                        },
                        views: {
                            haslocation: {
                                map: function (user) {
                                    if (user.location) {
                                        emit(user._id, user.email, user.location);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            email: {
                                map: function (doc) {
                                    emit(doc.email, doc);
                                }
                            },
                            docByEmail: {
                                map: function (doc) {
                                    emit(doc.email);
                                }
                            },
                            emails: {
                                map: function (doc) {
                                    emit(doc.firstName, doc.lastName, doc.email, doc.authVia);
                                }
                            },
                            googleUsers: {
                                map: function (doc) {
                                    if (doc.authVia == "google") {
                                        emit(doc.email, doc);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            fbUsers: {
                                map: function (doc) {
                                    if (doc.authVia == "FB") {
                                        emit(doc.email, doc);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            namesEmails: {
                                map: function (doc) {
                                    var firstName, lastName, name;
                                    if (doc.authVia == "BL") {
                                        firstName = "";
                                        lastName = "";
                                    }
                                    if (doc.authVia == "google" || doc.authVia == "FB") {
                                        if (doc.name) {
                                            firstName = doc.name;
                                            lastName = "";
                                        } else {
                                            firstName = doc.firstName;
                                            lastName = doc.lastName;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    emit(name, [firstName, lastName, doc.email, doc.authVia]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
        };

    constructor(

    ) {
    }

}
```

Comment: where is `emit()` defined?

Comment: I added `declare function emit(key: any): void;
declare function emit(key: any, value: any): void;` to my declarations.d.ts to resolve this issue... But it's rather a workaround than a solution...

Comment: Hey thanks, but now I have another error: 
`Typescript Error
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
src/providers/design-docs.ts
if (user.location) {
 emit(user._id, user.email, user.location);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad practice from CouchDB (see: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4624). To fix it you only have to declare the emit function (like @Phonolog said in his comment).

So before you call emit make this:

```js
Import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare function emit (val: any);
declare function emit (key: any, value: any);

@Injectable() export class DesignDocs {
...
```